# How do I get sprites to appear overtop of drawings?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

When making a drawing in pygame, for example the rectangle, how do I make my other sprites show up ontop of the rectangle? Currently they are underneath it

Comment: I believe it is all about the order things are drawn. Whatever is drawn last appears on top.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

when you draw all the objects, sprites should be last drawn on screen.
So first rectangles will be draw and sprites on top